# How to position image that has a jquery hover effect?

Tags: jquery, css, positioning

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("img.a").hover(
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
},
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
});

});
</script>
<style>
div.fadehover {
    position: relative;
    }

img.a {
    position: absolute;

        z-index: 10;
    }

img.b {
    position: absolute;

    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="fadehover" align="center">
<img src="Facebook.png" alt="" class="a" />
<img src="Facebook_hover.png" alt="" class="b" />
</body>
```

So I have this image fade hover effect on my image and it works fine. BUT i try to postition it where i want because now it is on the top left corner. How can I position the image in the center? or generally where I want? tried with simple center tags but doesnt work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the images inside their own divs inside the `.fadehover` div and apply the position styling to them and not the images.

**Edit: Code is as follows**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div.a").hover(
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
},
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
});

});
</script>
<style>
div.fadehover {
    position: relative;
}

div.a {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}

div.b {
    position: absolute;
}
</style>
<div class="fadehover">
    <div class="a"><img src="yourimage1.ext" /></div>
    <div class="b"><img src="yourimage2.ext" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks that works fine with my browser!  hope it will be in all browsers that way. I used exactly your code just edited also this one:

`div.fadehover {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px; /* replace with actual width */
    margin-left: 45%;
    margin-right: 50%;
    margin-top: 20%;

                  }`

Answer (score 0):

To position the image in the center, use:

```
div.fadehover {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px; /* replace with actual width */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```